# Elasticsearch match_phrase with slop

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch match_phrase query with slop=7. Based on the documentation for the slop parameter, I understand that for a query such as "brown fox" the documents such as "token1 token2 token3 brown token4 token5 token6 token7 fox" should be matched. However, I want to match all the documents containing either "brown" or "fox". Based on this article, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/slop.html, for 3 word queries, also documents matching only 2 query words are selected if slop is chosen correctly.

However, this is not the case for two word queries and documents containing only one of the query words, even if slop=7. What am I doing wrong? Did I misunderstood the behaviour of the phrase query/slop parameter?

Comment: sounds like you might want `match` query instead if you are okay with only matching one of your interest tokens ("brown" or "fox")

Comment: That's one of the options, but I was rather wondering why the query does not retrieve the documents containing only one of the query words. Should that not be the correct behaviour when using slop > 1?

Comment: because with match_phrase you are telling it to match **all** of the tokens, `slop` is the gap between tokens that is tolerated (tokens have to be adjacent if `slop = 0`)